# Efficient substring searching in Python with MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, database, binary-tree

I'm trying to implement a live search for my website.  One that identifies words, or parts of a word, in a given string.  The instant results are then underlined where they match the query.

For example, a query of "Fried green tomatoes" would yield:

```
SELECT * 
FROM articles 
WHERE (title LIKE '%fried%' OR
       title LIKE '%green%' OR
       title LIKE '%tomatoes%)
```

This works perfectly with a very small dataset.  However, once the number of records in the database increases, this query quickly becomes inefficient because it can't utilize indices.

I know this is technically what FULLTEXT searching in MySQL is for, but the quality of results just isn't as good.

What are some alternatives to get a very high quality substring search while keeping the query efficient?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) will help you to search fast within the huge amount of data

Answer (score 0):

they are many FULLTEXT search engine that you can use like [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) , [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), [Whoosh](http://whoosh.ca/) (it's pure python) and [Xapian](http://xapian.org/).  [django-haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) (if you are using django) which can interface with the 3 last ones;